# Visual Studio gray text background, how to remove it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2017

I have the following in a `cshtml` file 
[image]

It's not selected, it's like this, gray text background.

How to understand what is this text in the "font and color" settings, and reset it to the white/transparent normal background?

[image]

Comment: Have you got Find or Find and Replace open?

Comment: I have nothing open, this my "default" VS display of cshtml files... (

Comment: Oh, I think that's just how it looks in cshtml, so you can tell what's c# and what's html. Unfortunately I don't know how to disable it though.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable or change the background color for razor code as follows:
Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Environment/Fonts and Colors > Display items: HTML Razor Code Background; Item background:'Automatic'

Answer (score 2):

You can disable or change the background color for razor code as follows:
Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Environment/Fonts and Colors > Display items:HTML Razor Code Background.
To 'erase' change Item background from 'default' to 'white'